# Swift: FCM push notification not work if install by third party ( Not Registered error )

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, app-store, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my country exists a website for install `ios` application without the app store

This website sign `IPA` file and install on iPhones

If I compile my app via Xcode, FCM works fine. but if I signed my app via that website, FCM not work

Another codes and library work fine, just FCM not work

Also, after install token generate successful, but on send message i get error : `Not Registered`

Comment: It will not work, apple requires their certificates for stuff like that

Comment: Are you changing the bundle identifier while signing the IPA?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal no